# Why Firebase Realtime database is not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have written the code in Kotlin language
I need the firebase realtime database to add a child with user's UID with email as it's value under the users column when the user signs up. The Login is successful and then it passes to the main activity .The users details is listed in Authentication-> Users but the realtime database is not working and also when I click the back button it opens the main activity again and again ,after a number of clicks it goes back the login page and exits,maybe this is because it could not connect to the database.

Please help me with necessary changes. 
Here is the code

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
private var mFirebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics?=null

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var listofContacts = ArrayList<Contacts>()
    var adapter: ContactsAdapter? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mFirebaseAnalytics= FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)
        listofContacts.add(Contacts("NAME", 123456789))

        adapter = ContactsAdapter(this, listofContacts)
        listview.adapter=adapter
    }

    inner class ContactsAdapter : BaseAdapter {

        var contactslist = ArrayList<Contacts>()
        var context: Context? = null

        constructor(context: Context, contactslist: ArrayList<Contacts>) : super() {
            this.contactslist = contactslist
            this.context = context
        }

        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
            val contact = contactslist[position]
            val inflater = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            val myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_view, null)
            myView.name.text = contact.name!!
            myView.num.text = contact.num.toString()!!
            myView.setOnClickListener {
                val intent= Intent(context,ContactInfo::class.java!!)
                intent.putExtra("name",contact.name!!)
                intent.putExtra("num",contact.num!!)
                context!!.startActivity(intent)
            }
            return myView
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return contactslist[position]
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return contactslist.size
        }

    }
}
```

LOGIN

```
    private var mAuth:FirebaseAuth?=null

        var database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        var myRef=database.reference


        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        }

        fun loginevent(view: View){
           login(etun.text.toString(),pw.text.toString())
        }

        fun login(email:String,password:String){
            mAuth!!.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this){task ->
                    if(task.isSuccessful){

                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        LoadMain()
                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

        }

        override fun onStart() {
            super.onStart()
            LoadMain()
        }

        fun LoadMain(){
            var currentuser=mAuth!!.currentUser
            if(currentuser!=null) {            
           myRef.child("Users").child(currentuser.uid).setValue(currentuser.email)
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("email", currentuser.email)
                intent.putExtra("uid", currentuser.uid)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your `Login Successful` message tosted successfully?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes it is tosted sucessfully

Comment: Could you post the complete code for both activities?

Comment: Hvae you tried to add a complete listener to the `setValue()` method?

Comment: @Juanje I have added the complete code

Comment: @AlexMamo no I did not add it, may i know the details of it because i am new to programming

Comment: @ShafiqurRahman To the message that is coming from the Task, to see if you have proper permissions.

Comment: @AlexMamo kindly provide me the code to check it

Comment: How can I check whether i have the permission for accessing database ?